# Removing Javascript line breaks causing token identifier error

Tags: javascript, minify

This code produces no errors:

```
function func() {
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      /* stuff happens herer */
    }
  }
  func2(xmlhttp)
}
```

If I put all put all the code on a single line I get `SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier`

```
function func() { xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function stateChanged() { if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { /* stuff happens herer */ } } func2(xmlhttp) }
```

What difference does a single line make?

Comment: Semicolons. ASI (Automatic Semicolon Insertion), that lets them be optional in many cases, [does often depend on the presence of `LineTerminator`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846368) or line breaks.

Comment: but why minify manually when there are so many tools to handle that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's amazing what a difference having explicit statement separators (i.e. a semi-colon `;`) will do for you instead of depending on implicit ones (i.e.  carriage-return).  Try this:

```js
function func() { xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function stateChanged() { if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { /* stuff happens herer */ } }; func2(xmlhttp) }
```

The issue is that when you do your assignment ( `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =` ) the parser can't tell where the assignment should end without the author explicitly saying so.

Comment: I see, so you're saying that JS assumes, if no semi-colon is found, a line break is a good enough guess that it's finished? I didn't realize that a `}` could need a closing semi-colon.

Comment: Yes.  The answer that @JonathanLonowski linked gives a more complete answer, including references to the spec.  Some people will terminate every line with a semi-colon simply to eliminate the possibility of running into this issue.

Comment: What minifier are you using? All good minifiers can handle ASI properly.

Comment: I'm writing my own :/